# python 3.7.7 won't upgrade on mac after brew install?

Tags: python

my mac has python 2.7 so I did `brew install python3` I got this message

Warning: python 3.7.7 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 3.7.7, run `brew reinstall python`

but when I check the version I still have python 2?

```
~ ❯❯❯ python -V
Python 2.7.16
```

Comment: `python != python3`. Run the `python3` command, and things should be hunky-dory.

Comment: Then `python3` is not on your shell path: `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`. Or wherever homebrew installed it.

Comment: yeah it's working now. So I can't run my py program using `python` but `python3`? it's so wierd in the future there might be python4?

Comment: Don't go down that rabbit hole :). The 2-vs-3 war has been raging for over a decade.

Comment: so as a beginner I should just ignore the version 2 and go ahead with 3?

Comment: Unless you have a _very_ good reason to use 2, then yes.